# Non-rectifiable curve

Tags: real-analysis

I have this problem.

> Let $f(x)$ be the Weierstrauss function. Show that the curve $\rho : [0, 1] \to \mathbb R$ defined as $\rho(x) = (x, f(x))$ is not rectifiable.

Here is my approach. We know that a curve is rectifiable iff its length is finite, and we know that the length is equal to the integral of the distance between the curve and a fixed point over the interval of definition of the curve. Pick the origin as said fixed point. The distance between $(x, f(x))$ and the origin is $\sqrt{x^2 + f(x)^2}$ for each $x$. The integral of this distance over the interval $[0, 1]$ is then infinite, since $f(x)$ is unbounded. Thus $\rho$ is not rectifiable.

Does this proof make sense? Is there another more flexible way to do this? Are any of my assumptions wrong?
Thank you for your help. I have worked on this for a while, so feel free to share any solutions you may have.

Answer (score 2):

*A super quick way to attack this problem:*

Note that any rectifiable curve is of bounded variation, and any function of bounded variation is differentiable almost everywhere. As the Weierstrass function $f$ is nowhere differentiable, it is not of bounded variation, and so $\rho$ is not rectifiable either.

Comment: Is there a more elementary way to demonstrate this?

Comment: @NicoKonrad The answer is not as non-elementary as it seems - it is known that a curve $(x,f(x))$ has finite length if and only if $f$ is of bounded variation, so the two concepts are essentially the same.